GIN an empty request body is sent to the server c.Request.Body
I'm doing a test project to learn how to develop. I have a certain page, there is an authorization form on it. At the front, I form a json object from the login and password fields and then pass it to the body via fetch. But the problem is that I get an empty value in go. I tried to do this through the standard http package in go and it worked for me, but going to the basics of GIN I get an empty value
My code on site
<script>
                function GetData() {
                    let username = document.querySelector('#username');
                    let password = document.querySelector('#password');
                    var data1 = JSON.stringify({
                        "username": username.value,
                        "password": password.value
                    });
                    fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Length': data1.length
                        },
                        body: data1
                    })
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => console.log(data1))
                        .catch(error => console.error(error));
                }

</script>

and in go, I'm trying to get the value like this
c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
    resp := make(map[string]string)
    resp["unAuth"] = "Unauthorized"
    resp["Auth"] = "Success"

    var creds Credentials
    err := c.BindJSON(&creds)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error is",err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ошибка декодирования json", err)
        log.Println("значение username", creds.Username)
        log.Println("значение password", creds.Password)
        c.JSON(500, gin.H{
            "status": "Failed",
            "error":  fmt.Sprintf("%s", err.Error()),
        })
        return
    }

where is my mistake on the front or backend part?
I've tried various variations like and nothing helped
c.GetRawData()
io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
jsonData := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&creds)


What is the raw data you're reading from the body? What is Credentials?

What's the error returned? Also, can you share your full handler code?
